# React e Redux - atualizar estado com botão

Tags: javascript, react, redux

Tenho um botão na minha aplicação que abre um Modal. Estou implementando redux na aplicação, e agora não estou sabendo fazer o botão funcionar novamente. Estou utilizando um estado fixo enquanto ainda aprendo a usar o redux melhor.

Esse é o reducer que estou usando:

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux'

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    lista: () => ({
        tarefas: [{
            nomeTarefa: 'teste redux',
            subtarefa: [{
                _id: 1,
                nomeSub: 'teste redux dnv',
                status: false
            },
            {
                _id: 2,
                nomeSub: 'hmmsw',
                status: true
            }],
            data: [{
                dia: 2,
                mes: 4,
                ano: 2020
            }],
            completas: 1,
            incompletas: 1
        }]

    }),
    modal: () => ({
        show: false
    })
})

export default rootReducer
```

As ações que quero que atualizem o atributo "show" (esse é o arquivo que está dando erro):

```
export const handleModal = event => ({
    type: 'ABRIR_MODAL',
    payload: { ...lista, show:true }
})

export const closeModal = event => ({
    type: 'FECHAR_MODAL',
    payload: { ...lista, show:false }
})
```

O reducer das ações:

```
const INITIAL_STATE = { show: false, tarefas: [] }

export default (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
    switch(action.type) {
        case 'ABRIR_MODAL':
            return { ...state, show: action.payload }
        case 'FECHAR_MODAL':
            return { ...state, show: action.payload }     
        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

E o erro que estou recebendo:
[[image: 1]

Answer (score -1):

Sugestão: Por padrão, atenta-se a codar em inglês !!!

```js
export const handleModal = event => ({
    type: 'ABRIR_MODAL',
    payload: { ...lista, show:true } // remover "...lista"
})

export const closeModal = event => ({
    type: 'FECHAR_MODAL',
    payload: { ...lista, show:false } // remover "...lista"
})
```

```js
export default (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
    switch(action.type) {
        case 'ABRIR_MODAL':
            return { ...state, show: action.payload } // action.payload.show
        case 'FECHAR_MODAL':
            return { ...state, show: action.payload } // action.payload.show
        default:
            return state
    }
}
```